# android connect to oracle databases using maf

Tags: android, web-services, rest, jdeveloper, oracle-maf

I have been googled everywhere but no clear answer I've got..
I'm building android application that connects & synchronizes oracle database when there is internet else it get its data from interior stored data..
the question is: what the most secured and effective approach..

is it MAF with REST service?
what about using jdeveloper for this task?
My application deal with secured credentials and get very personal data to display to my users.

users those are interested in, are near 2000 users.

Answer (score 1):

MAF can't be directly connected to a database (expect for the local SQLite DB). So if you want to consume data from your 'external' DB you will need to expose it as a web service. So yes, a REST service is a way to do this.

Oracle MAF applications can be developed by using JDeveloper or [Eclipse](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/downloads/index.html).

Comment: User404, thank you for interest, my question is:is it preferable approach?
are there problems in performance?

Comment: No since the majority of the mobile apps work this way. Security is also covered in MAF (just check the documentation / developers guide).

Answer (score 0):

note that the SQLite database in MAF can be create such it is encrypted requiring a password to be opened. The MAF documentation is detailed on this. For REST, its a transport layer security you want to build on the REST service side of things.

Frank